# Is it possible to add text and numbers into the same column/field of attributes of a shapefile in ArcGIS 10.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, arcgis-10.3

I have to add a field to the attributes of a shapefile and the data reads as:

2
BDL
22
18
11
BDL
BDL
25
3

Could these data be added to the same field/column of the attributes of the shapefile in arcmap 10.3?

Comment: Yes, just use a text (string) type field. (This has more to do with the limitations of a shapefile than your version of Arcmap, although it is appreciated that you include software version :) )

Comment: dBase String fields are limited to a width of 254 (254 ASCII7 characters, fewer when using UTF-8 multi-byte codepoints), but there is no restriction on the formatting.
This may, however, violate database design best practice by storing delimited sets in a single field instead of normalizing to a 1:Many related table.

Answer (score 2):

To combine text and numbers in a field, you need to make a text (string) type field. You won't be able to do math with your numbers in a text field (if you have letters in it as well).

This is a property of the shapefile itself, and is not directly related to your software (eg. Arcmap).